# Pygame: TypeError: Argument must be a sequence of rectstyle objects

Tags: python, class, object, methods, pygame

I'm trying to add a basic collision detection to a simple platformer game. I have a class Player, and when the player collides with a platform I want to print ("Collision"). I have created all of my platforms using a Platform class, and appended them to a list for which my method refers to collidelistall(platforms) to check for collision. Why am I getting this error? What does my list contain, if not rect objects? I've posted the relevant segments of code, but I'll post the entire thing if needed.

Thanks.

```
class Platform():
    def __init__(self, platformx, platformy):
        self.x = platformx
        self.y = platformy


    def draw_platform(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, (self.x, self.y, 40, 20))


class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Player1.png').convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def display_player(self):
        return self.image

    def is_collided_with(self):
        return self.rect.collidelistall(platforms)


pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY, FLAGS, DEPTH)
pygame.display.set_caption('Rum Islands')
generate = Player()
man = generate.display_player()

platforms = [] 

loop = True
while loop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT \
            or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
            loop = False


    if generate.is_collided_with(): #check for collision
        print("True")

    screen.fill(WHITE)

    platform_x = 0
    platform_y = 0

    for row in level:
        for col in row:
            if col == "P":
                col = Platform(platform_x, platform_y)
                col.draw_platform()
                platforms.append(col)
            platform_x += 15
        platform_y += 20
        platform_x = 0
```

Comment: use `print()` to see what you have on list. BTW: always put fill error message (traceback) in question (not only part of message, and in title). there are other usefull information - ie. which line makes problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collidelistall` expects list of objects `pygame.Rect()`. Your class `Platform` is not `pygame.Rect()` which has not only `x` and `y` but other parameters and methods.

So try

```
class Platform(pygame.Rect):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.Rect.__init__(self, x, y, 40, 20)

    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, self)
```

---

**BTW:** don't use in methods unknow variables - like `screen` in your `draw_platform`. Better send it as argument or set in `__init__` so you could use `self.screen`.

And you don't have to add everywhere word `platform` - ie. `platformx`, `platformy`, `draw_platform` - you have this word already as class name `Platform`. If you will create new class ie. `class House(Platform)` then it will be look strange `house.draw_platform(...)`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've encountered another issue, it's giving me bizarre return values for supposed collisions. I start the game with the player not touching any of the platform objects,but if I call return self.rect.collidelistall(platforms) i get thousands of collisions.

Comment: if you do nothing with collision then it find the same collision in next loop - and `while True` is executed thousands times in one second. Function `collidelistall` returns list of elements which collide with player so you can print it and see what you get - maybe you collide with elements which you didn't expect.